# How to make a native windows application?

Tags: windows, native

I do most of my development for the Android platform, and have developed applications for Windows in the past too. However, when I have developed windows applications, I've always used  the .NET framework. This requires the end user to have the .NET framework installed on their machine.

What programming languages and associated tools can I use to create an application that will run on a windows PC (XP and greater) (other operating systems are welcome) with no need to have frameworks such as .NET and Java installed first?

Many thanks, Todd

Comment: Im not sure if this will be any help to you but I've just started looking at the Win32 API with C++. Cold, hard C++! I heard its easier to use C but Im more of an OO fan to be fair. Best of luck =) Also, I use the VS 10 compiler on my local machine but Borland compiler elsewhere (Borland has been renamed now, im not sure what to )

Comment: What compiler and editor do you use?

Comment: Get Petzold's "Programming Windows" and a C compiler.  When you worked through the book, you'll know everything you need to know about native winapi programming.

Comment: If i'm on my laptop I use the Borland c++ compiler and Windows Notepad as my editor or if I am at home on my main machine I'll use visual studio 10 as editor and compiler and if im at college we'd be using Visual c++ express 2008 i believe.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most Ms Windows apps are developped with C++ (or C), accessing to Win32 API for GUI for example. You may also use some other languages that compile to x86 code and are able to access to regular Win32 DLLs if you need them (for input, GUI, etc., see [Win 32 API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_API)), like Pascal.

The second most used tool to build MS Windows applications with some forms must be VB up to VB 6 (that is, before VB.net), then probably Delphi.

Comment: What compiler and editor do you use?

Comment: Personally, VC6 (editor and included compiler) and Delphi 5 (the same), but you'll probably like [Visual C++, express edition available](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/visual-cpp-express)

Comment: Does Visual Studio allow you to compile code that doesn't require .NET?

Comment: @Todd Davies: Yes. Non-.NET mode is the default mode for Visual C++ compilers. But do get something newer than VC6. Get at least the VC++ 2008 compilers as they are much more compliant to the C++ standard than VC6 is.

Comment: Yes, In Silico is right, I was answering previous question, but link above goes to 2010 edition (VC6 is 12 years old). Ms C++ compilers can compile to .Net and native since 2003. C++ for .net ("managed") is only a special use of it, not the default one (specific syntax needed).